# Колка и рубка дров

Tags: терминология

Известно, что выражение *"колка дров"* гораздо популярнее выражения *"рубка дров".* Меня интересует, *можно ли вообще говорить **рубка дров** и, если да, то в чём разница.*

Ясно, что *колуном* только *колют дрова*, но *с участием топора* тоже часто говорят о *колке дров.* Возникает предположение, что последние правы и что *колкой* можно называть все описанные действия, а вот *рубкой* то ли также можно называть *колку топором* (тогда это взаимозаменяемые термины исключительно в этом случае), то ли это вообще неправильный термин, применяемый дилетантами.

Повторюсь, что это были мои рассуждения, которые могут быть совсем неправильными. Рад буду услышать правильную трактовку этого вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Ушакова:
[**рубить**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1012170/%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC), рублю, рубишь, *несовер.*
**1.** *кого-что.* Резать, разделять на части, ударяя острием с размаху. Рубить ветви. Рубить шашкой неприятеля. Рубить мясо. **Рубить дрова топором.**

*Мать Гордея Татьяна Власьевна, крепкая старуха 70 лет, **рубит колуном дрова.** <…> Старуха прекращает **рубить дрова**, держит топор* (Д. Мамин-Сибиряк. [Золото](https://books.google.ee/books?id=GtzMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT455&lpg=PT455&dq=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=98zOkk0fs0&sig=ACfU3U0_XL7fybwEUmwThctbL2DDxbitbw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiizYPC-oTiAhUntYsKHQ40CPo4FBDoATADegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false)).

*Я уже понял, как это правильно делается, и я понял, что **сырые дрова тоже рубятся.** И на следующий день утром **я рубил дрова** и, знаете, устал* (С. Ковальчук).

Колоть – разделять чурбак или полено на крупные фрагменты с помощью колуна. Тяжелый, с тупым лезвием, он "расклинивает" толстые чурбаки, деля их на части. Облегченные колуны имеют форму лезвия в виде заточенного клина или классическую – "под топор".

Рубить – разделять на более мелкие части, отрубать сучки, рубить тонкие деревья (поперёк). Рубят обычно поленья потоньше, а также делят их топором на щепки и растопку.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Нравится мне Ваш ответ!

Comment: Благодарю. Отдельно  – за "также" (иссомневалась вся, дважды исправляла).

Comment: **...рубит колуном дрова.** Конечно. А как же? Не напишешь же *колет колуном*? Ну а раз уж эта старуха рубила, то потом и прекратила рубить. Всё логично.

Comment: Рад стараться. :) Да, непонятно, почему рубит колуном (старуха)... Ведь колуном же можно только толстые чурбаки колоть!

Comment: Понятия _колоть_ и _рубить_ в некоторых случаях (по отношению к дровам) сложно различить. Смотрите: КОЛО́ТЬ; несов., перех. (сов. расколоть). Рассекать, расщеплять или раздроблять на части ударами чего-л. Колоть дрова. Колоть орехи. Колоть сахар. _Он достал из-за пояса **топор,** присел на пол и начал **колоть** лучину._ Тургенев, Бирюк.  https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/колоть Думаю, что такой глагол был выбран во избежание повтора.

Comment: Участника @Niemand заминусовали, а ему лишь нужно было добавить оговорку. В разных регионах говорят по-разному, и искать здесь какую-то литературную норму, на мой взгляд, бессмысленно. Там, где я вырос, дрова кололи. "Рубить дрова" мы встречали только в книжках да слышали по телевизору. (При этом мой отец мог хмыкнуть, мол, "разе(sic!) дрова рубят? Рубят деревья!". То есть, применительно к древесине была чёткая разница: вдоль волокон - колют, поперёк - рубят. "Колоть колуном" было бы воспринято абсолютно нормально. Другое дело, что так никто бы говорить не стал, просто потому, что - зачем? ..

Comment: .. "Колол дрова" - и ладно. Если только собеседник спросит: "Чем колол-то?", тогда уточнят - колуном, топором или кувалдой с клином (это для особо сложных случаев применяют). Ну или если детей учат: "Эти, здоровые, лучше колуном (колоть), а эти и топором можно".

Comment: Точнее: "Здоровые-то лучше колуном, а эти и топор возьмёт". Слово "колоть", действительно опустят - лишнее. Ну и, соответственно, "рубить колуном" звучало бы как оксюморон, и выдавало бы человека городского или сильно нездешнего.

Answer (score 2):

Тоже хотел написать про волокна: скол, колоть - это по трещине, по слабому месту. А рубить/резать - именно поперек волокон, то есть рубят сильное место, а колют в точке, по линии, с помощью сосредоточения силы в одном месте, одним точным удара ударом. То есть принципы колоть и рубить разные.

Рубить можно дерево, можно лес, можно срубить=вырезать+строить дом. Рубить связано с р+у+бить, то есть разрушать образуя новую границу объектов. А когда колют, не разрушают внутреннюю структуру. Рубить/срубить ~ ограничить.

Насчёт *рубить дрова* - можно говорить, но это будет именно заготовка леса маленькими бревнами, которые потом расколют на дрова/поленья, то есть тоже самое, что *рубить лес*, хотя дрова можно рубить уже из срубленного дерева, но это никак не колка дров. Хоть рубить/валить лес могут для не только для дров, а скажем для превращения в бревна для производства, а не для топки, либо рубить лес можно для прореживания определенных участков. Можно *рубить лес на дрова*.

То есть *рубить/валить лес* и *рубить дрова/нарубить дров* может иметь значение "запасти бревен для растопки", хотя немного разные процессы. Сами бревна не хранят расколотыми, а колют по мере необходимости на поленья, которыми уже топят.

Answer (score 1):

Дрова колят вдоль волокна.
Рубят-поперёк

Comment: Рубить — рубят, колоть — кол**ю**т.